# Android: Connect to socket server on emulator from physical device

Tags: android, sockets, networking, android-emulator, port

I'm trying to connect to a socket server that's running on a android emulator on my computer, from a physical device. I have no problem using the emulator as the client and connecting to my device but when i try to do the opposite it wont connect.

Comment: No/Yes indeed. You better not try to spend your time on this. Way to complicated

Comment: @greenapps but is it possible to get it working?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/connect-android-device-to-server-in-emulator

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to get it working on MacOS Sierra

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 4444 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4444

" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```